# Navigation Page Exception in C# using Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I have implemented a hybrid web view in my Xamarin PCL app.

I am calling a C# function from an Html page using JavaScript in the aforementioned, hybrid web view.

The problem is that although my function is being called, an exception is thrown when I try to redirect from it.

> Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException:
>
> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
>
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.

My code is as follows:

```
var isValid = AreCredentialsCorrect(user);

if (isValid)
{
    try
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new UserDashboard("local.html?auth_admin=true"));

    }
    catch { }

}

public UserDashboard(string uriname)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    hybridWebView.Uri = uriname;

    hybridWebView.RegisterAction(data => userLogin(data));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you're trying to update UI from a background thread. Try doing the navigation from the main thread:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await Navigation.PushAsync(new UserDashboard("local.html?auth_admin=true")));
```